# Why am I getting a rate limit error when I use the openai api for my first time?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "myapiKey"

completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Give me 3 ideas for apps I could build with openai apis "}])
print(completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

This is my code that I am trying to run. But whenever I run it, I keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/easwar/Downloads/ChatGPT API/01 chatgpt simple", line 5, in <module>
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Give me 3 ideas for apps I could build with openai apis "}])
  File "/Users/easwar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/openai/api_resources/chat_completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/easwar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
  File "/Users/easwar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 298, in request
    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
  File "/Users/easwar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 700, in _interpret_response
    self._interpret_response_line(
  File "/Users/easwar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 765, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.
```

The main error is at the bottom.

[usage limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r428a.png)
This is what my usage limit looks like on the openai website. I don't understand why most of it is expired because this is my first time using the api.

I would be really thankful to anyone who can help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue during my first time.
The problem is not from you code.
You have just used up you API key quota.
And the only way that you can fix it is by creating a very new OpenAI account, and then requesting for the key on that one.
It will definitely work.
Be careful not to use same details as this other accounts.